# Show only particular fun spots from Google Places API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using this Google Places API on my react native project - https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete

My code:

```
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete'
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete placeholder='Search'
            query={{key:'',components: 'country:us'}}
            onPress={(data, details) => {
                //console.log(data.description)
            }}
/>
```

Anyone have an idea how to limit the results to just 'restaurants in new york'?

Thanks

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/AppAndFlow/react-native-google-autocomplete/issues/18 

Pay attention to the queryTypes prop.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get for autocomplete is `establishment`. See types in [table 3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table3).

Please +1/star this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/35820774).